# filter child collection by list

Tags: linq, filter

I'm having som issues filtering child collection by list

My datamodel is as follows;

```
  class Catalog
  {
      public int ID { get;set;}
      public string Name { get;set;}
      public IList<Area> Areas { get;set;}
  }

  class Area
  {
      public int ID { get;set;}
      public string Name { get;set;}
  }
```

Lets assume i have the following data:

```
       List<Catalog> dataSource;
       List<Area> filter;
```

I would like to filter the datasource by the filter, something like

```
    from v in dataSource where v.Areas.Contains(filter) select v
```

but that doesnt Work.

Instead i can do as follows

```
      List<Catalog> result = new List<Catalog>;
      foreach (Area area in filter)
      {
                result.AddRange((from v in dataSource where v.Areas.Contains(area) select v).ToList());
       }
```

But that not optimal.

Can anyone tell me how to filter a child Collection by a list

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from v in dataSource where v.Areas.Intersect(filter).Any() select v;
```

This works because `Intersect` returns what both lists have in common, and if they have anything in common then they match.

Comment: doesnt Work i just do a lot of brute force in LinqPad until i breake it

Comment: @KeldJakobsen Sorry, I can't undestand your question.